# Opening files from directory, and keeping file name and content

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-3.6

I would like to read all files from a directory, and import both filename and content into a list. I wrote the following code, but it only imports only the last file in the directory.

```
import os

fileList = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    f = open(file, 'r')
    contents = f.read()
    newItem = (file, contents)
    fileList.append(newItem)


print(fileList)
```

Comment: In case you're wondering that you didn't get an answer for this somewhat simple question sooner: the `python-3.6` tag should be used for questions that are specific to python version 3.6. Since this question doesn't require a specific version of python, you can add the `python` tag. There are a lot more people following questions that are tagged with `python` than `python-3.6`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the indentation. Try this:

```
import os

fileList = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        f = open(file, 'r')
        contents = f.read()
        newItem = (file, contents)
        fileList.append(newItem)

print(fileList)
```

Additionally, you're not closing the files in your program which isn't good style. It's better to use a so-called context manager that handles opening and closing the file:

```
import os

fileList = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            contents = f.read()
            newItem = (file, contents)
            fileList.append(newItem)

print(fileList)
```